# Is there a way to take multiple means and store them in a vector in R

Tags: r, subset, mean

I would like an easier way to do what this does

```
MEAN1 = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == 1 | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE)  
MEAN2 = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == 2 | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE)  
MEAN3 = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == 3 | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE)  
MEAN4 = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == 4 | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE)  
MEAN5 = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == 5 | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE)  
MEAN6 = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == 6 | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE)  
MEAN7 = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == 7 | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE)  
MEAN8 = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == 8 | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE)  
MEAN9 = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == 9 | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Doing the following doesn't seem to work

```
AGE_GROUPS = seq(1, 16, 1)  
MEAN = mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == AGE_GROUPS | CIS2017$ALFSTN == 1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data so we can run your code

Comment: Try `sapply(AGE_GROUPS, function(x) mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == x | CIS2017$ALFST == 1], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Matt, as a "best practice", it might be more useful to you do store the means in a named-list or named-vector instead of individual variables. For instance, ThomasIsCoding's answer converts a names list to individual variables in your global environment, but if you remove the `list2env` and `envir=` from it, you will have a list of things you can work on. From there, using `sapply` or `lapply` functions (or their kin), it's easy to apply a single function or command-sequence to all of the means in one motion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are after

```
list2env(setNames(
  lapply(AGE_GROUPS,
       function(k) mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == k | CIS2017$ALFSTN == 1], na.rm = TRUE)),
  paste("MEAN",AGE_GROUPS)),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

or

```
v <- setNames(
  sapply(AGE_GROUPS,
       function(k) mean(CIS2017$USHRWK[CIS2017$AGE == k | CIS2017$ALFSTN == 1], na.rm = TRUE)),
  paste("MEAN",AGE_GROUPS))
```